# Error when trying to use casting, java

Tags: java, casting, instanceof

I have this method where I want to be able to determine if two cells are equal, where "equal" means they have the same position. I have written this code where I use both `instanceof` and casting to make sure that my object is of the type `Position` and then cast it to the type `Position`, but it does not seem to work for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
public class Postion {

    private int column;
    private int row;

    public Position (final int column, final int row)  {
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Position) {
            Position position = (Position) other;
            return ((column == other.getColumn()) && (row == other.getRow()));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error code, in fact I get an error code for both of the `get` methods:

```
error:
cannot find symbol
return ((column == other.getColumn()) && (row == other.getRow()));
^
symbol: method getRow()
location: variable other of type Object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return ((column == other.getColumn()) && (row == other.getRow()));
```

should be

```
return ((column == position.getColumn()) && (row == position.getRow()));
```

Object doesn't contain `getColumn()` and `getRow()` methods, it is position, so you need to use position there.

Comment: Thanks guys! That did indeed help :)

Keep up the supportin'! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You used the Object other instead of the typed Position object position.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename

```
Position position = (Position) other;
```

to

```
Position otherPos = (Position) other;
```

then use

```
otherPos.getColumn()
```